# can not convert string to float sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I wrote this program, but i get error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float
```

My code:

```py
import sqlite3
from sklearn import tree


database = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
c = database.cursor()

x = []
y = []

for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM cars'):
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
ml = clf.fit(x,y)
```

edit: I read this link (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) but i do not know how to use label encoder in this app - please help me to use label encoder or solve this problem

Comment: Can you implement the concept of label encoding from scratch? I mean the use of the built-in function is not allowed or the concept itself too?

Comment: hi , i dont know how to use it , using it is alowed

Comment: Can you then provide a data sample of `y` so I can work with it and post an example on how to use it?

Comment: x[0] : فروش پراید صبا 89پایه گازسوز تمیز
y[0] : ۷۹,۰۰۰,۰۰۰

Comment: Well I don't know what I'm seeing here, but I will provide an answer with a dummy `y` variable so you can examine and replicate in your code.

Comment: @AbbottTaft Please remember to post your comments in English; Stack Overflow is an English-language site, and many of us here don't understand Arabic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example how to use `LabelEncoder` properly:

I created a `y` list which contains some strings:

```
dummy_y = ['label1', 'label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label77']
```

We want to encode each element in the list to a numeric value, `LabelEncoder` maps each string value to a corresponding numerical value.

First import the `LabelEncoder` class & create an instance of it:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
```

Now we can `fit_transform` our dummy list which means that the instance will first map each string to a value with `fit` and then will actually apply it with `transform`:

```
encoded_dummy_y = le.fit_transform(dummy_y)
```

will return:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Where `0` corresponds to `label1`, `1` to `label2` etc.

Comment: thanks , but i have this error: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 2.  6.  5.  3.  8.  4.  0.  1. 10. 12.  7. 11.  9.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: It tells you how to fix it.

Comment: thanks a lot , yes , i fixed this but i have an other error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nimafanniasl/nahaii/main_ml_app.py", line 19, in <module>
    x = le.fit_transform(x)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_label.py", line 115, in fit_transform
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1024, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (1, 13) instead.

Comment: You understand that I can't solve issues based solely on error messages, right? debug your code and work through it, it tells you what the errors are.

Comment: ok , thanks a lot